# Query with explain("executionStats") in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I have a problem with requests including `explain`.
As an example, the following request works well :

```
pp.pprint(
  col.find(
    {"cuisine":"Italian"},
    {"name" : 1, "address.zipcode" :   1, "address.coord" : 1}
  ).explain()
)
```

The list of items of the `explain` method is well printed.

However when I want only the `executionStats` item from the `explain` method, with the following request :

```
pp.pprint(
  col.find(
    {"cuisine":"Italian"},
    {"name" : 1, "address.zipcode" :   1, "address.coord" : 1}
  ).explain("executionStats")
)
```

I have the following error :

```
TypeError: explain() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Does anyone knows what it is about and how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 6):

In pymongo, `explain()` is a dictionary, so you need to add the key to show `executionStats` :

```
col.find(
  {"cuisine":"Italian"},
  {"name" : 1, "address.zipcode" :   1, "address.coord" : 1}
).explain()['executionStats']
```

Comment: Format it and please add some explanation

Comment: How to do the same for aggregate?

Comment: it fails for `aggregate` saying `cursor` doesn't have `explain`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass "executionStats" to explain in pymongo.  You must let pymongo's explain wrapper grab all of the explain output and parse out what you need.

```
pp.pprint(
  col.find(
    {"cuisine":"Italian"},
    {"name" : 1, "address.zipcode" : 1, "address.coord" : 1}
  ).explain()
)
```

See https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html?highlight=explain#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.explain

There are no arguments.