# Using PyMongo how can I do .explain() for a distint command

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

using mongo shell we can do explain of a distinct command like this
db.collection.explain("executionStats").distinct(
    "key", 
    { "q_filed": { $exists: true } }
)

how can I do .explain() the same using python/pymongo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query with explain("executionStats") in pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142061/query-with-explainexecutionstats-in-pymongo)

Comment: As i know, current common mongo recommendation for `explain` is to use runCommand either in the driver or in the shell. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75789808/how-to-check-mongodb-updateone-execution-time/75789922#75789922. I don't know whether pymongo is an exception in this recommendation or no though

Comment: thanks @dododo
`db.command({"explain": {"distinct": collection,"key": distinct_key,"query": query} })` I can do it this way.